# Using a regex within Sublime Text results in running out of stack space error

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Within sublime text I'm trying to match a **single** double quote followed by the html tag `<br>`.  Any string can come after the html tag and the double quote must not be preceded by a double quote.

I've gotten as far as having my regex meet my expectations when testing in https://regex101.com/r/HHNB1E/4.

This is my regex: `^((?!").)*{"<br>}.*$`.

However, when I put this into Sublime Text it throws the error "Ran out of stack space trying to match the regular expression".  I'm assuming my regex is inefficient given I am not very experienced with them.

Example results expected:

`foobar""<br>` - No match

`foobar"<br>` - Match

`""<br>baz` - No match

`"<br>baz` - Match

`foo<br>baz` - No Match

Do I need to improve the regex for efficiency or am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce given your inputs, the matches / non-matches seem to be working just fine for me in Sublime 3.1.1. Note that rather than repeating a negative lookahead plus `.`, you can use a negated character set instead: `[^"]*`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  There's about 20k lines in the document I'm searching

Comment: *I'm trying to match a single double quote...* what you are trying to match could be done by `"(?<!"")(?=<br>)`. You don't need all that stuff.

Comment: The [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) must be the culprit, and the efficient equivalent for `((?!").)*` will be `[^"\r\n]*` (CR and LF are added to prevent overflowing to the next line in the text editor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are seeing is much probably because of capturing group involved. Turn it to  non-capturing group like this:

```
^(?:(?!").)*"<br>.*$
```

But...

> I'm trying to match a single double quote...

If you are trying to match one double quotation mark that is immediately followed by `<br>` and is not preceded by another `"` then chances are you need lookarounds:

```
"(?<!"")(?=<br>)
```

Above is a fast solution to your problem.

Comment: I used `"(?<!"")(?=<br>)` and it worked to achieve my goal.  Turns out I didn't know enough about regex to know that the other answer (and my attempt) would return the entire line.  Upvoting both because they both search successfully without the error.  Thanks for taking the time to really see the problem I was trying to solve :D

Comment: +1 ty.  had `(^|[^\\s])([\\w\\d])+\\.([\\w\\d])+\/[^\\s]*` and removed uselessly captured groups to solve this issue. final regex now easier to read: `(^|[^\\s])[\\w\\d]+\\.[\\w\\d]+\/[^\\s]*` _(this regex finds urls embedded in text...note that http/s is ignored)_

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this using a negated character class instead of a tempered greedy token/negative lookahead:

```
^[^"]*"<br>.*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0lsY2D/1)

The regex can be further simplified if you do not need to select the whole line: `[^"]"<br>`

If you need the full line and the above does not work I'd recommend running the pattern via `grep`

```
grep -P '^[^"]*"<br>.*$'
```